# xp how do you uninstall visual studio sp1 ?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I saw this in a section here but I do not know how you add the parms for this some one posted this soulution I have the program downloaded and I try it in a run window when I add the uninstall force it says the program name is invalid VS10sp1-KB983509.exe /uninstall /force
can some one explain how to do this???

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). This question belongs on superuser.com (Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can go to "Add/Remove Programs" and it should be listed under that.